# How to export 2730 Table with different name?

Tags: export, list-manipulation, data

I have 2370 table which I need to export in cvs format with different name  and I don't want to do it manually. Let say I have this 3 tables:

```
table1=Table[{i,i+1},{i,1,8}]
table2=Table[{j,2*j},{j,1,12}]
table3=Table[{k,5+k},{k,1,4}]
```

I tried to export them by For loop (which did not work) by below code.

```
For[i=1,i<=3,i++,Export["tablei.cvs",tablei,"Table"]]
```

What is the right way to do it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use this. But if you use `tableXXXX`, use the method in the comment.

```
table[1]=Table[{i,i+1},{i,1,8}]
table[2]=Table[{j,2*j},{j,1,12}]
table[3]=Table[{k,5+k},{k,1,4}]
```

```
Export["table"<> ToString[#] <>".cvs",table[#],"Table"]] &/@ Range[1,3]
```

Comment: All of my table are inside another table so I can access to them just by tableformt[[i]] (tableformat is the name of the table of the table that I have), above solution works but problem is that it create list not table in cvs format.

Comment: I can export them one by one by this command (Export["1.cvs", tableformat[[1]], "Table"]) then export all of them by For loop or Do or another Table but problem is how to change the name for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that may help.  Consider the following three functions.  The first function, `tname`, returns a table name as a string.  For example, "table0053".  The second function, `fname` returns a file name.  For example, "table0053.csv".  The third fundtion, `vname`, returns a variable name.  For example, `table0053`.

```
ClearAll[tname, fname, vname, "table*"]
tname[n_] := "table" <> StringJoin[ToString /@ IntegerDigits[n, 10, 4]]
fname[n_] := tname[n] <> ".csv"
vname[n_] := ToExpression[tname[n]]
```

We can use these functions to generate the tables.  Importantly, in order to use `vname` on the left of the = (`Set` command), we must `Clear` the variable name and use `Evaluate`.  The following code creates three variables, `table0053`, `table0192` and `table2301`.

```
Evaluate[vname[53]] = Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 1, 8}];
Evaluate[vname[192]] = Table[{j, 2*j}, {j, 1, 12}];
Evaluate[vname[2301]] = Table[{k, 5 + k}, {k, 1, 4}];

table2301

(*  {{1, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 9}}  *)
```

To list the names of all of the table variables, use `Names["table*"]`.  Now we can export a single table like this

```
Export[fname[2301], vname[2301], "CSV"];
Import[%, "Text"]

(*  "1,6
    2,7
    3,8
    4,9"  *)
```

A sequence of tables can be exported like this

```
Do[Export[fname[k], vname[k], "CSV"],
 {k, {53, 192, 2301}}]
```